# LinkedIn login script not working in opera

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using an LinkedIn script for login to my website, it seems to work well in all browser but it is not working in Opera. It opens an blank linked-In authentication pop-up window.

Below is my code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function() {onLinkedInLogin();});
}

function onLinkedInLogin() {
IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl","industry","location","headline"])
.result(function(result) {
})
}
</script>
<script type='IN/Login' data-onAuth='onLinkedInLogin'></script>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

there are known issues with Opera and the LinkedIn APIs - essentially, the LinkedIn plugins use a scripting mechanism that is not supported by Opera:

https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/11392#comment-11392